# Responses of MS sql queries to different request are getting mixed on apache tomcat server

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jsp, webserver

I have a web application whoses task is to show image and id no of employee based on events getting registered in MS SQL Data base. I'm selecting last(latest) event occurred for two inputs (readers) and showing image and id no of employees. I am refresing the web page every 500ms to update any new event with respect to the inputs(reader). When I am using only one client application works properly however with multiple clients (running parellel browsers with diffrent input (reader) selected) I am getting Image of other clients mixed.( i.e. Consider opening the url at two location and selecting input1 and 2 for one browser(1) and input 3 and 4 for other browser(2). Ideally browser(1) should show image only from input 1 & 2 and browser 2 should show images from input 3 & 4 But browser(1) is showing images of browser(2) and browser(2) shows images of browser(1) also.) Below is my web page code please suggest the solution.

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    <%@ page import="javax.sql.*;" %>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table, th, td {
              border:1px solid black;
              border-collapse: collapse;
              text-align: center;
             }
            </style>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>PoP UP DISPLAY</title>
        <script >
        window.setInterval('refresh()', 800);
        // Call a function every 800 milliseconds
        // Refresh or reload page.
        function refresh() {
            window .location.reload();
        }
         </script>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color: black;">
     <jsp:declaration>
        String reader1 ="";
        String reader2 ="";
        String image1 ="";
        String image2 ="";
        String empCode1 ="";
        String empCode2 ="";
        String empName1 ="";
        String empName2 ="";
    </jsp:declaration>
    <jsp:scriptlet>
        reader1 = request.getParameter("reader1");
        reader2 = request.getParameter("reader2");
    </jsp:scriptlet>
    
    <%

    java.sql.Connection con1;
    java.sql.Statement s;
    java.sql.ResultSet rs1, rs2;
    java.sql.PreparedStatement pst;

    con1=null;
    s=null;
    pst=null;
    rs1=null;
    rs2=null;

    // Remember to change the next line with your own environment
    String url=
   "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP_Address_Of_DB/ DB_Name;instance= INSTANCEB";
    String id= "user_id";
    String pass = "user_pass";
    try{

    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    con1 = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
    cnfex.printStackTrace();

    }
    String sql1 = "select top 1 * from ecbacs.EventLog where ReaderId= '"+reader1+"' order by EventNo desc";
    String sql2 = "select top 1 * from ecbacs.EventLog where ReaderId= '"+reader2+"' order by EventNo desc";
    %>
    <%
    try{
        s = con1.createStatement();
        rs1 = s.executeQuery(sql1);
            while( rs1.next() ){
            empCode1= rs1.getString("EmpCode");
            empName1= rs1.getString("CardHolderName");
            }
        s = con1.createStatement();
        rs2 = s.executeQuery(sql2);
          while( rs2.next() ){
            empCode2= rs2.getString("EmpCode");
            empName2= rs2.getString("CardHolderName");
            }
        image1 = empCode1+".png";
        image2 = empCode2+".png";
    %>

    <table style="height:100%;width:100%; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;border:1px solid">
     <tr style="height: 95%;">
         <td><img alt="Employee1 Photo"  style="height: 100%" src="images/<%=image1%>"</td>
         <td><img alt="Employee2 Photo"  style="height: 100%" src="images/<%=image2%>"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td style="color:#ffffff; font-size: 2em"><%= empName1 %></td>
    <td style="color:#ffffff; font-size: 2em"><%= empName2 %></td>
    </tr>
    </table>


    <%

        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        finally{
        if(rs1!=null) rs1.close();
        if(rs2!=null) rs2.close();
        if(s!=null) s.close();
        if(con1!=null) con1.close();
        }

        %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am running the above applcation on Apache tomcat version 6. Please see the above code and help me with the solution. also is there any other way to achieve the above funtionality please suggest. I am a beginner with web programming also not from computer science background.

Comment: There'no any problem defined by your code rather than unnecessary refreshing a page. Define your problem or error that you getting and add a code to reproduce it.

Comment: I am refreshing the page to show real time data.

Comment: Real time data cannot be shown from inputs.